# Convert Sequence of Keystrokes into a Price

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to set up a `TextBox` in a C# / Windows Forms project so that when the user types in a price using the keyboard or numpad, the text box will format the input sequence to look like a price.

Example: user types 1-5-0 (minus the dashes), the text box's text value will be $1.50.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
private string KeySequence;

// ...

private void TxtValue_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if(char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        KeySequence += e.KeyChar.ToString();

        if (KeySequence.Length > 0)
        {
            txtValue.Text = "$" + (decimal.Parse(KeySequence) / 100).ToString("0.00");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, whenever I type in a value, the first character is always the last key that I typed, followed by the "$" and the price. So if I type 150, the formatted text shows up as: `0$1.50`.

I was thinking this is due to the `KeyDown` event being invoked before `KeyPress`, so I tried to suppress it with handling code for that:

```
private void TxtValue_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    txtValue.Clear();
}
```

But that's still not working.

Anything I can do to stop that first character from showing up?

Comment: To cancel the keystroke, set `e.Handled` to `true`

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `KeyPress` event, the keystroke will still be processed by the control.

To prevent this, set `e.Handled = true;` in the event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a custom control that inherits from `NumericUpDown`.  Then, you would have a control that is designed specifically for dealing in numbers, automatically handles decimals places and thousands separators, provides UP and DOWN controls for easy incrementing, and can append/prepend the appropriate currency symbol.

I'm stealing the formatting portion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751838/adding-a-sign-to-numericupdown-value-like).  Using that, your new class would look something like:

```
public class NumericUpDownCurrency : NumericUpDown
{
    public NumericUpDownCurrency()
    {
        DecimalPlaces = 2;
        Increment = 1;
        ThousandsSeparator = true;
    }

    protected override void UpdateEditText()
    {
        ChangingText = true;
        var decimalRegex = new Regex(@"(\d+([.,]\d{1,2})?)");
        var m = decimalRegex.Match(Text);
        if (m.Success)
            Text = m.Value;
        ChangingText = false;
        base.UpdateEditText();
        ChangingText = true;
        Text = Value.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

Add that class to your project and build.  You should then see `NumericUpDownCurrency` in the toolbox, allowing it to be dropped on a form.  The control does the rest.